# Sencha Locationupdate event working even if gps is turned off

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am using Ext.util.Geolocation library in Senchatouch.There are two listeners namely locationupdate which fires when the users co-ordinates are obtained and locationerror which is fired when there is a error in fetching the user co-ordinates. Now even when I turn the gps off on my android device the locationupdate event is fired.I would like to know if the locationupdate listener is a measure to check if the gps is active or not or I need to try a different way.Experts Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check carefully your device location settings, this would happen to me on Android if I switch off the geolocation service but leave the google wifi location active.. hth.